# Is this the correct way to train SRGAN?

Tags: pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

I am training SRGAN from scratch but am facing a lot of issues. The output of generator is just noise and the discriminator loss is stuck. Would be great if someone can help me debug my code.

```
from torch.nn.modules.loss import BCELoss

def train_model(gen, disc):
  for epoch in range(200):
    run_loss_disc = 0
    run_loss_gen = 0
    for data in train:
      low_res, high_res = data[0].to(device, non_blocking=True, dtype=torch.float).unsqueeze(1),data[1].to(device, non_blocking=True, dtype=torch.float).unsqueeze(1)
      #--------Discriminator-----------------
      
      gen_image = gen(low_res)
      disc_gen = disc(gen_image.detach())
      disc_real = disc(high_res)
      p=nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
      loss_gen = p(disc_real, torch.ones_like(disc_real))
      
      loss_real = p(disc_gen, torch.zeros_like(disc_gen))
      loss_disc = loss_gen + loss_real
      opt_disc.zero_grad()
      loss_disc.backward()
      opt_disc.step()
      run_loss_disc+=loss_disc.item()
      #---------Generator--------------------
      disc_gen = disc(gen_image)
      cont_loss = vgg_loss(high_res, gen_image)
      adv_loss = 1e-3*p(disc_gen, torch.ones_like(disc_gen))
      gen_loss = cont_loss+(10^-3)*adv_loss
      opt_gen.zero_grad()
      gen_loss.backward()
      
      opt_gen.step()
      
      run_loss_gen+=gen_loss.item()
    print("Run Loss Discriminator: %d", run_loss_disc)
    print("Run Loss Generator: %d", run_loss_gen)
```

Comment: As far as I remember, the original paper pretrained the generator using `MSELoss(gen_image, high_res)` first (no discriminator at all) and only then enabled the discrimination and VGG loss. Perhaps a small multiplier for `cont_loss` (like 5e-3) would help getting some traction in your case?

Comment: that still does not solve the issue.